# Windows 10 system files taking 190GB

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, filesystems, storage

I have a Samsung SSD 840 EVO of 250GB as my main drive with Windows 10 Pro N and it shows up as being almost full, although I don't have too much stuff in it, but when I took a look to the storage use I found this:

[image: SSD shows up as almost full]

And the detail for System and reserved:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: Use WinDirStat to find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that Redis was the culprit... There were a bunch of RedisQFork_XXXX.dat files inside Windows > ServiceProfiles > NetworkService > AppData > Local > Redis that were taking all the space, so my question is related with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662131/rediss-huge-files-wont-delete just in case someone has the same problem. @DanielB, you can post that as an answer as I wasn't able to find those files with the Windows explorer, but they showed up with WinDirStat!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears some application has mistakenly saved a lot of/big files in your Windows directory, making Windows see it like system data.

Using [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/), you can easily identify where the culprits are.

Be careful though when deleting data: Do not delete essential system files/folders, like the “WinSxS” folder. Doing so may cause Windows to stop working sooner or later.